# Find all integers $n$ (positive, negative, and zero) so that $n^2 + 1$ is divisible by $n + 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I found $n=0, n=1, n=-2,$ and $n=-3$, but I am having trouble showing that these are the only four.

I was thinking about maybe showing that no integer on the intervals $(-\infty, -3), (-3, -2), (-2, 0),$ and $(0, 1)$ can satisfy the requirement that $n+1 | n^2 + 1$, but that seems very complicated for something that seemingly should be easier to prove.

Answer (score 2):

As  $$n^2+1=2+(n-1)(n+1)$$

we need $(n+1)|2$

Answer (score 1):

Easier to note that if $n+1|n^2+1=(n+1)^2-2n$, then $n+1|-2n$, which doesn't allow many choices.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Clearly $n+1\mid (n+1)(n-1)$, that is, $n+1\mid n^2-1$.  Therefore
$$n+1\mid n^2+1\quad\hbox{if and only if}\quad n+1\mid\bigl((n^2+1)-(n^2-1)\bigr)\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ n\!+\!1\mid f(n)\iff n\!+\!1\mid f(-1),\, $ for $\,f(x)\in\Bbb Z[x],\,$ by Factor Theorem or congruences.

Answer (score 0):

continuing Ross Millikan's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1827/ross-millikan),

$(n$+1)|$($n$+1)^2, $n$+$1$|$n^2+1 $\implies $(n+1)|2n

Clearly, $n$+$1$|$n$ is not correct, so $(n+1)|2 which means

```
n+1 = -2 or
n+1 = -1 or
n+1 = 1 or
n+1 = 2
```